# Hashtables at the exam

Tags: algorithm, hashtable

I failed my algorithm exam in January. I'm going to an oral exam tomorrow. I was going through the ordinary exam and answers, when there was an answer I couldn't understand. [image: Here is the question]

According to the answers, the answer is A. Why? 20 mod 7 is 6, but 12 mod 7 is 5 and it is empty. Hope that you would help me out here.

PS: Sorry if the formatting is wrong

Comment: don't forget to multiply k by 2

Comment: then (2*20+3*0^2) mod 7 is 5. And the 5th slot is empty

Comment: and that's where 20 is in answer a)

Comment: slot number starts with 0 ..

Answer (score 0):

```
h(20,0) = 5
h(12,0) = 3
h(5,0) = 3*
h(5,1) = 6
h(3,0) = 6*
h(3,1) = 2
h(1,0) = 2*
h(1,1) = 5*
h(1,2) = 0

* collision
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i    k 
-------------------------   
0    20    (2*20+3*0^2) mod 7 = (40 + 0) mod 7 = 40 mod 7 = 5 <- [e, e, e, e, e, 20, e]
0    12    (2*12+3*0^2) mod 7 = (24 + 0) mod 7 = 24 mod 7 = 3 <- [e, e, e, 12, e, 20, e]
0     5    (2*5+3*0^2) mod 7 = (10 + 0) mod 7 = 10 mod 7 = 3  <- collision
1     5    (2*5+3*1^2) mod 7 = (10 + 3) mod 7 = 13 mod 7 = 6  <- [e, e, e, 12, e, 20, 5]
0     3    (2*3+3*0^2) mod 7 = (6 + 0 ) mod 7 = 6 mod 7 = 6   <- collision
1     3    (2*3+3*1^2) mod 7 = (6 + 3) mod 7 = 9 mod 7 = 2    <- [e, e, 3, 12, e, 20, 5]
0     1    (2*1+3*0^2) mod 7 = (2 + 0) mod 7 = 2 mod 7 = 2    <- collision
1     1    (2*1+3*1^2) mod 7 = (2 + 3) mod 7 = 5 mod 7 = 5    <- collision
2     1    (2*1+3*2^2) mod 7 = (2 + 12) mod 7 = 14 mod 7 = 0  <- [1, e, 3, 12, e, 20, 5]
```

So

```
[1, empty, 3, 12, empty, 20, 5]
```

Comment: Why is the i only 0, 1 and 2, and not 3?

Comment: For each number `k` you start with `i = 0`. For each collision you increment `i` and calculate the quadratic hash function until you find an empty slot. In this specific question you never reach `i = 3` since you will find an empty slot for `k = 1` when `i = 2`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it works, each time collision happens, quadratic probing is going to be used (with `i=1,2,..`) until there is a free space available in the hash table:

[image]